# Number of connected components created by a complex closed curve

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Given a complex curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$, I was wondering if it is possible to have infinitely many connected components in $\mathbb{C}\setminus Im(\gamma)$.
I thought about the following example:

Using the Hawaiian earring $H$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) with radius $\frac{1}{n^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}$, the circumference of the "earring" at step $n$ would have length $\frac{2\pi}{n^2}$ and thus we would have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\pi}{n^2} \to c$ with $c$ finite. Based on that I thought it could be possible to define a curve $[0,1]\ni x\mapsto\gamma(x)\in H$ parametrized in a way that makes a point on the earring correspond to the length reached at that point in the sum (made opportunely continuous). In this way, when $x = 1$ (that is $c$ in our parametrization), $\gamma(1)=0$ and as such our curve is closed.

I have absolutely no clue on how to formalize this concept and no clue as to whether it holds true or not. I would like to know if this method actually works and, if so, how would you tackle this proof? If it doesn't work, are there easier examples of this fact, or is it simply not true? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is true. If you don't ask anything more than continuity of $\gamma$, you can have pretty pathological loops $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb C$.  With your example, you can make it $C^1$ I think.

A way to formalize your idea would be to consider the family of parametrized loops $\gamma_n(t)=\frac{1}{2^n} (e^{2i\pi 2^n t}-1)$: each of them parametrizes a circle of radius $2^{-n}$ passing through $0$, with bounded speed. You can concatenate those curves by defining $\gamma(t):=\gamma_n(t)$ if $t \in [\sum_{k \leq n-1} 2^{-k}, \sum_{k \leq n} 2^{-k}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the curve defined by

$$\gamma(x)=
\left\vert \left(x -\frac{1}{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right\vert$$ for $\frac{1}{2} < x \le 1$, $\gamma(x)=-\gamma(1-2x)$ for $0 \le x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\gamma(1/2)=0$.

It satisfies the requirements you’re looking for. The two parts are glued on the $x$-axis to have an infinite number of loops.